# Item template for TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using `TabControl` to present data from different `DataTable`s. With this XAML code:

```
<TabControl Margin="5, 5, 5, 5" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            DockPanel.Dock="Top"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemInfoViewModels}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding EditingTable.Name}"></TextBlock>
            <ContentControl>
                    <Partials:ItemInfo />
                </ContentControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

I get a view that looks like this:

[image: TabControl view]

which is obviously wrong. Everything - header text and content - is displayed where normally `Header` would be shown. So how can I change my XAML, so that it would look as it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ContentTemplate` instead of `ItemTemplate`. `ItemTemplate` is applied to the `Header` of each `TabItem`, `ContentTemplate` is used to display the selected tab.

You could alternatively set the `ItemContainerStyle` and manipulate the settings on the `TabItems` more directly.